# Populate a WTForms SelectField with an SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, flask, wtforms

I'm want to populate a WTForms SelectField with the rows returned by this query:

```
cur.execute("SELECT length FROM skipakke_alpin_ski WHERE stock > 0")
```

The query returns rows with the ski length of different types of skis. `cur.fetchall()` returns the following tuple:

```
[(70,), (75,), (82,), (88,), (105,), (115,), (125,), (132,), (140,), (150,), (160,), (170,)]
```

How would I go about to do add these numbers to a `SelectField`, so that each ski length would be its own selectable choice? If I had done this manually, I would have done the following:

```
ski_size = SelectField('Ski size', choices=['70', '70', '75', '75'])
```

... And so on for all of the different lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by doing the following:

```
def fetch_available_items(table_name, column):
    with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT length FROM skipakke_alpin_ski WHERE stock > 0")
        return cur.fetchall()

class SkipakkeForm(Form):
    alpin_ski = SelectField('Select your ski size', choices=[])

@app.route('/skipakke')
def skipakke():
    form = SkipakkeForm

    # Clear the SelectField on page load
    form.alpin_ski.choices = []        

    for row in fetch_available_items('skipakke_alpin_ski', 'length'):
        stock = str(row[0])
        form.alpin_ski.choices += [(stock, stock + ' cm')]
```

Answer (score 6):

In one of the projects I have used like below:

models

```
class PropertyType(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

and in forms

```
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField

class PropertyEditor(Form):
    property_type = QuerySelectField(
        'Property Type',
        query_factory=lambda: models.PropertyType.query,
        allow_blank=False
    )
    //Other remaining fields
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The solution might look like the code below.

Let's assume you have two files: `routes.py` and `views.py`

In `routes.py` file you put this

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField

# Here we have class to render ski
class SkiForm(FlaskForm):
    ski = SelectField('Ski size')
```

In `views.py` file you put this

```py
# Import your SkiForm class from `routes.py` file
from routes import SkiForm

# Here you define `cur`
cur = ...

# Now let's define a method to return rendered page with SkiForm
def show_ski_to_user():
    # List of skies
    cur.execute("SELECT length FROM skipakke_alpin_ski WHERE stock > 0")
    skies = cur.fetchall()

    # create form instance
    form = SkiForm()
    # Now add ski length to the options of select field
    # it must be list with options with (key, value) data
    form.ski.choices = [(ski, ski) for ski in skies]
    # If you want to use id or other data as `key` you can change it in list generator
    if form.validate():
        # your code goes here

    return render_template('any_file.html', form=form)
```

Remember that by default `key` value is unicode. If you want to use int or other data type use `coerce` argument in SkiForm class, like this

```
class SkiForm(FlaskForm):
    ski = SelectField('Ski size', coerce=int)
```

Comment: Excellent answer. It helped me to solve the problem that I found with the validation of the form. Congratulations on your excellent understanding of the concept. The comment on 'UNICODE' is the key Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

I had quite simmilar problem, and here is my workaround

```
class SkiForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        cur.execute("SELECT length FROM skipakke_alpin_ski WHERE stock > 0")
        skies = cur.fetchall()

        self.ski_size.choices = [
            (ski , ski) for ski in skies
        ]

    ski_size = SelectField("Ski size")
```

**Explanation:**

We modified original `FlaskForm`, so that it executs database query each time when it is being created.

So `SkiForm` field data choices always stays up to date.