# I'm having a problem populating a flask wtform stringfield with data from a FK related mysl table

Tags: mysql-python, flask-wtforms

These are the related tables:
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXpJ4.jpg)
I have managed to populate the stringfield, with some help from another question here, but the problem is that the dropdown only displays the second row twice when clicked.
[web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWmES.png)
Where have I gone wrong? This is my code.

form created in forms.py

```
class AddProductForm(FlaskForm):
    productcode = StringField(label='Product Code', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=10)])
    description = StringField(label='Description', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    producttype = StringField(label='Type', choices=[], validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Add')
```

routes.py

```
# Edit product
@prod.route('/edit_product/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_product(id):
    form =  UpdateProductForm()
    # Create cursor
    cur = db.get_db().cursor()

    # Get product by id
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_ID = %s", {id})
    prod = cur.fetchone()
    cur.close()

    def fetch_machtype():
        cur = db.get_db().cursor()
        types = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM machinetypes')
        return cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
        

    # Get Form  
    form = UpdateProductForm()

    # Clear the SelectField on page load
    form.producttype.choices = []        

    
         
    
    
    form.productcode.data=prod[1]
    form.description.data=prod[2]
    for row in fetch_machtype():
        m_type = int(row[0])
    form.producttype.choices += [m_type, m_type]
    
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():

        form = UpdateProductForm()
        code = form.productcode.data
        description = form.description.data
        ptype = form.producttype.data

        # Create Cursor
        cur = db.get_db().cursor()
        # Execute
        cur.execute ("UPDATE products SET prod_code=%s, prod_descr=%s, mach_ID=%s WHERE prod_ID=%s",(code, description, ptype, id))
        # Commit to DB
        db.get_db().commit()
   
        #Close connection
        cur.close()    # 
        

        flash('Product Updated', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('product.product'))

    return render_template('add_editproduct.html', form=form, legend="Edit Product")
```

I would also like the form to show the user the data field in the dropdown, but use the ID field in the update function, as the ID field is meaningless to the user. Please assist with this as well.

i used a code snippet from this link [Populate a WTForms SelectField with an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548561/populate-a-wtforms-selectfield-with-an-sql-query)

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3OKu.jpg)